# google-cloud-pubsub push continues to retry even after getting HTTP 200/202/204

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

We publish a message using google-cloud-pubsub topic which has a cloud run push subscription. The cloud run service acknowledges the message as soon as it receives it by sending a 204/200. 
Despite the acknowledgement the pubsub continues to retry. This implementation is based on https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/system-packages

Is there a way to ensure pubsub does not retry after an ack. I am wondering if the only way to fix this to implement a middleware and reject repeated messages.

```js
app.post('/deploy/environment', (req, res) => {
    try {
        if (!req.body) {
            const msg = `No Pub/Sub message received`;
            logger.error(`error: ${msg}`);
            res.status(202).send(`Bad Request: ${msg}`);
            return;
        }
        if (!req.body.message || !req.body.message.data) {
            const msg = `Invalid Pub/Sub message format`;
            logger.error(`error: ${msg}`);
            res.status(202).send(`Bad Request: ${msg}`);
            return;
        }

        const dataUtf8encoded = Buffer.from(req.body.message.data, 'base64').toString('utf8');
        logger.info(`Message content: ${dataUtf8encoded}`);
        let content;
        try {
            content = JSON.parse(dataUtf8encoded);
        } catch (ex) {
            logger.warn('Bad request invalid JSON');
            return res.sendStatus(202);
        }
        if (!content.environmentId) {
            const msg = `EnvironmentId is a mandatory parameter`;
            logger.error(`error: ${msg}`);
            res.status(202).send(`Bad Request: ${msg}`);
            return;
        } else if (!content.environment) {
            const msg = `Environment is a mandatory parameter`;
            logger.error(`error: ${msg}`);
            res.status(202).send(`Bad Request: ${msg}`);
            return;
        } else if (!content.roles) {
            const msg = `Roles is a mandatory parameter`;
            logger.error(`error: ${msg}`);
            res.status(202).send(`Bad Request: ${msg}`);
            return;
        }
        res.status(204).send();
        runSystemPackage(content.environmentId, content.environment, content.roles);
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error(`error: ${err.message}`);
        res.status(202).send(`${err}`);
    }
});
```

Logs:

```
"2019-06-12T04:49:44.015789Z"  POST /deploy/environment 204 1ms 
"2019-06-12T04:49:44.014897Z"  Message content: {"environmentId": "5","environment": "pvs5", "roles": ["core"]} 
"2019-06-12T03:42:22.251890Z"  Message [object Promise] published. 

Snippet showing retries:
"2019-06-12T04:57:01.167608Z"  POST /deploy/environment 204 1ms 
"2019-06-12T04:56:43.233886Z"  POST /deploy/environment 204 39ms 
"2019-06-12T04:55:33.630202Z"  POST /deploy/environment 204 0ms 
"2019-06-12T04:55:12.609798Z"  POST /deploy/environment 204 0ms
```

Comment: 1) How do you know that a 200/204 is being returned? Edit your question and post your Stackdriver logs showing the Cloud Run service being called. I have implemented Pub/Sub with Cloud Run in a number of projects without problems after I fixed my coding bugs. One issue that I see is runSystemPackage. For debugging change PubSub Subscription "Acknowledgement Deadline" to be 600 seconds. The default is 10 seconds. If runSystemPackage takes longer than 10 seconds, that's your problem.

Comment: I added some log snippets. If you notice I send a 204 before I call the runSystemPackage as I noticed in the logs that the Acks were getting delayed when I waited for it to complete. There is no code path in my sample which sends anything except HTTP 2xx. I though see Pub/Sub continuing to retry. I am testing with 600 secs ack now.

Comment: You cannot send the HTTP 204 before runSystemPackage. When your code returns an HTTP response, your code is no longer executing. You are assuming that the 204 is sent at that line of code. Note: The message does not show 600 second delays between messages. Also, don't truncate logs. I need to see the start and end times of the HTTP Request/Response, not the final response.

Comment: I think you are right, after increasing the timeout to 600 seconds I don't see retries. And I suspected that the order of res.status(204).send() did not matter and it looked to be waiting for runSystemPackage to complete. There are a lot of logs which I couldn't share and therefore truncated. Thanks